# Firefox Developer Edition displaying image incorrectly?

Tags: css, firefox-developer-edition

Not sure what's going on here. I have an image with a width of 25%, and it's being displayed at about 4.6% the width of its parent div.

This happens only in Firefox Developer Edition
(normal Firefox, Safari, and Chrome all display correctly).

I've tried clearing all the data a couple times, this did not fix the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you use Firefox Deveolper Edition while in Normal Firefox work?

Comment: As Firefox Deveolper Edition is not stable version , Try Clear cache or Restart Browser?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any add-ons that could mess with page content? Or an adblocker?  Those can cause issues.

Comment: Adblocker don't mess up pages it can be another types of extension

Comment: They can if they are changing CSS as many do, such as ublock origin.

Comment: Just asking for my Products , Thanks